# Facing issues in installing packages in aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cloud9

I am new to using AWS CDK, I had imported aws_stepfunctions_tasks from aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks link given: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks/DynamoPutItem.html
but it is showing an import error. Other than that all the imports I have used are working fine. I even tried installing it through pip using different versions and the version which I want but it is giving me the error attached below. Can someone please help out with this issue. I have written the code in my stack file. This issue had occurred also when I was using s3_deploy. I didn't still find a solution for it. [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CDK dependencies have changed between V1 and the [recently released CDK V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html). Make sure you are not mixing V1 and V2 dependencies.  Here is a Python example for both versions from [aws-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/python/api-cors-lambda):

### CDK V2

`requirements.txt`

```
aws-cdk-lib>=2.0.0
constructs>=10.0.0
```

`app.py`

```py
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    App, Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as _apigw
)
```

### CDK V1

`requirements.txt`

```
aws-cdk.core
aws-cdk.aws_lambda
aws-cdk.aws_apigateway
```

`app.py`

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as _apigw
)
```

Comment: I found a way around somehow, using pip3 instead of pip. That worked.

Comment: V1 vs V2 wouldn't explain not being able to install V1 modules via pip.

Comment: @gshpychka The question's title is _Facing issues in installing packages in aws cdk_.  Others landing on this link may find this general information helpful.  SO's true power is to help others, not just the poster.